# How to insert 'n' values in hypertable using Hadoop Python?

Tags: python, hadoop, hypertable

How to insert multiple values in hypertable using Hadoop Python streaming? I am able to insert values for single column, but not more than one column. While I'm trying, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Unable to write cell - java.lang.Exception: incorrect output line format only 1 tabs
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:259)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:253)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to write cell - java.lang.Exception: incorrect output line format only 1 tabs
    at org.hypertable.hadoop.mapred.TextTableOutputFormat$HypertableRecordWriter.write(TextTableOutputFormat.java:247)
    at org.hypertable.hadoop.mapred.TextTableOutputFormat$HypertableRecordWriter.write(TextTableOutputFormat.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$3.collect(ReduceTask.java:496)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed$MROutputThread.run(PipeMapRed.java:381)
```

map.py

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

reduce.py

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
        txt= line.split('\t')
        print txt[0]+'\t'+txt[1]+'\t'+txt[2]
```

Input form hypertable will be tab separated values, 
    ex : "this    is    text".

Output table contains three columns, I need to split the input text by tab and save it into hypertabel.
     Hypertable output column names `cc`,  `kw` and `oc`.

Comment: try showing what you exactly try, not just the error, every little bit helps!